# Invoke initialize database function from views

Tags: python, pyramid

My web application has a template that allows user to upload a file. The file's content is stored in a variable.

I want the file to be passed on to the views(views.py), which in turn would invoke a function inside the initializedb.py script. I want just *that* function to get executed and not the entire initializedb.py script(which involves numerous insertions). My initialize DB function takes in a .csv file as input and inserts its contents into the database.

My question is **how do I invoke the function which is inside initializedb.py through my views?**

inside my template:-

```
$.post(
    "{{request.route_url('passer_view')}}", // view that should invoke the insert function
    {'data': filecontents} //file contents will be my global variable that holds the contents of the file
);
```

my views.py:-

```
@view_config(route_name='passer_view' renderer="mytem.pt")
def insert(request):
    data = request.POST["data"]
    csvify_data(data) #this function makes renames the data into a csv file
    ###i should invoke the initializedb.py function here
    return HTTPFound(location=...)
```

my initializedb.py:-

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    #a whole load of engine creation and stuffs
    with transaction.manager:
        def insertfunction(csvfile):
            DBSession.add(...)
```

How can this be done?Is there any other way to do what I am doing? Any idea is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to restructure your initializedb.py. A function defined inside another function is not accessible from outside. Better to define them at module level, and simply call them inside your main function: then you can also import them and call them from anywhere else.

Comment: I sorta get you.  Now, I should just put those functions outside my initializedb into some other .py file and then import the function into my views?

Comment: You can do that, or you can just put them at the top level inside initializedb, as long as they're outside of the main function.

Comment: Okay I get you. But in that case should I instantiate another transaction manager? like with transaction.manager: above the main function?